# I want to post data with some objects (images) to my php

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code. all those data are normal (json) but the files are objects(images) i need to post them to my php but when i try to submit the following i get a false response (the files are accepted but the json data are missing).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_save_motor_quote.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:{ 
    policyStartDate : policyStartDate,
       noYearLicense : regNo ,
       regNo : regNo ,
       chassisNo : chassisNo ,
       vehicleType : vehicleType ,
       bodyType : bodyType,
       make : make,
       modelType : modelType,
       model : model,
       ccHp : ccHp,
       cylindersNo : cylindersNo,
       seatingNo : seatingNo,
       regMonth : regMonth,
       vehicleReplacmentDays : vehicleReplacmentDays,
       vehicleValue : vehicleValue,
       ncb : ncb,
       coverCode: coverCode,
       cpr: cpr,
       addCover: addCover,
       saveQuote : saveQuote,
       premium : premium,            
       file_ncb : file_ncb,
       file_cpr : file_CPRFront,
       file_cpr_back : file_CPRBack,
       file_license : file_LicenseFront,
       file_license_back : file_LicenseBack,
       file_vehicle : file_vocF,
       file_vehicle_back : file_vocB,
       file_last_insurance : file_insCard,

    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
      alert(res);
},
error: function(res){
    alert(res);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to convert your image to base64 string and send it to your server? Then you can decode base64 string in your php and save it to file.

Please, try to describe your question in more general way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the dataType key

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/get_save_motor_quote.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{ 
     policyStartDate : policyStartDate,
     noYearLicense : regNo ,
     regNo : regNo ,
     chassisNo : chassisNo ,
     vehicleType : vehicleType ,
     bodyType : bodyType,
     make : make,
     modelType : modelType,
     model : model,
     ccHp : ccHp,
     cylindersNo : cylindersNo,
     seatingNo : seatingNo,
     regMonth : regMonth,
     vehicleReplacmentDays : vehicleReplacmentDays,
     vehicleValue : vehicleValue,
     ncb : ncb,
     coverCode: coverCode,
     cpr: cpr,
     addCover: addCover,
     saveQuote : saveQuote,
     premium : premium,            
     file_ncb : file_ncb,
     file_cpr : file_CPRFront,
     file_cpr_back : file_CPRBack,
     file_license : file_LicenseFront,
     file_license_back : file_LicenseBack,
     file_vehicle : file_vocF,
     file_vehicle_back : file_vocB,
     file_last_insurance : file_insCard,

  },
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
      alert(res);
    },
  error: function(res){
    alert(res);
  }
});
```